# How do I set Ron and Roff for SBreak switch in PSpice or OrCAD capture?

Tags: switches, power-electronics, pspice, orcad

I am using SBreak but when I click in the properties I only see: Model, REDFES, TEMPLATE, SIMULATION ONLY, and PKGREF.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your question, but whoever did should have explained to you why they did it, and it is most likely due to insufficient effort in asking  the question. Here is an example of a related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102175/how-to-use-voltage-controlled-switch-in-orcad

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it can't be more clear! what is clear is that you don't understand the question because you don't know the answer. I need to set Ron and Roff in a SBreak switch in PSpice. Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the SBreak, then go to Edit, Model and click: Edit Instance Model (Text)...

You can change the value of RON and ROFF there.